# Windows 8 command line for Open With dialog

Tags: java, windows-8, file-association, rundll32, open-with

What is the Windows 8 version of the "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL {path}" command?

I am trying to get the open with dialog in Java, which works in Windows 7, but does nothing on Windows 8

```
...
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("rundll32",  "shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL",   
    file.getAbsolutePath() );
pb.start();
...
```

My Googling for the command, or information that could help me put it together myself has so far been fruitless...

Comment: What is the intention behind doing that? Wouldn't `Desktop.open()` be the better choice?

Comment: Did not know about that class, thank you! But I still needed the OpenWith dialog as well, and after searching the registry for the action on unknown file types, I found the functionality is now in the form of a standalone executable: C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on its usage?